# Is that possible to create cluster Autoscaler in kubeadm cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, kubeadm

I have created Kubernetes cluster with Kubeadm tool on AWS. What are all the possible ways to Autoscale the node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about all the ways to scale a Kubernetes cluster on AWS. However I would argue the best approach would be to use the [Kubernetes Cluster Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws). It can dynamically scale out a cluster based on scheduled pods in the cluster (as opposed to something like autoscaling groups that can only schedule based on node resource usage). Even for AWS EKS it is now [the documented approach to autoscaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cluster-autoscaler.html).

Comment: Is cluster Autoscaler is possible in kubeadm cluster?

Comment: Yes it is just deployed as a regular Kubernetes Deployment. If you are familiar with Helm you can also deploy it as Helm chart.

Comment: I don't know helm. And also new to this topic can you explain me in brief? Also we have to write deployment file any sample is there?

Comment: Helm is callled the Kubernetes Package Manager. It allows you to "package' your kubernetes objects into a single chart. E.g. instead of creating a custom deployment.yaml you can install the existing AWS Cluster Autoscaler chart using helm so you don't have to worry about figuring out the configuration of the cluster autoscaler, you only need to tweak the chart a bit to your use case.

Comment: cluster autoscaler scales the cluster so it scales master node also?

Comment: No I don't think so. Master nodes are not as easily added as other nodes. But by default you don't schedule any pods on your master nodes anyway. There is no need to dynamically scale your master nodes in most situations.

Comment: so i have both master and worker node where should i give the deployment command in master or worker? If I give in master will it work for worker also?

Comment: The deployment command will send a command to the Kubernetes API. The Kubernetes API will deploy the Cluster-autoscaler in your cluster. The cluster-autoscaler in turn listens to changes in Kubernetes Resources (e.g. creating new deployments) and based on that determines whether the cluster needs to scale.

Comment: so it means I can deploy anywhere

Comment: Exactly. It does not matter on which node you use kubectl to deploy as eventually everything passes through the Kubernetes API anyway

Comment: thank you for your response.. one more doubt so i have to give clustername so how I will get cluster name ?

Comment: @harini-nathan, Were you able to setup cluster autoscaler using kubeadm? Facing similiar workflow issues?

Comment: @Blokje5 The hard part with kubeadm clusters and `cluster-autoscaler is to get the worker nodes to join the cluster... The normal method to do that involves a recently-obtained token from the control-plane... (For EKS IAM and the aws-auth configmap is used to authenticate the nodes to the control-plane, which allow them to add themselves)

Answer (score 0):

If you have auto scaling group for the slave nodes in your aws cluster, then you can certainly install Kubernetes Cluster Autoscaler.
Please check out this [cluster-autoscaler bash script](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/addons/cluster-autoscaler/cluster-autoscaler.sh) and as it is for kops, you can actually use it to learn how many steps and resources you have to follow/configure to install autoscaler.

1. First create iam policy

```
printf "   a) Creating IAM policy to allow aws-cluster-autoscaler access to AWS autoscaling groups…\n"
cat > asg-policy.json << EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
                "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingInstances",
                "autoscaling:DescribeLaunchConfigurations",
                "autoscaling:DescribeTags",
                "autoscaling:SetDesiredCapacity",
                "autoscaling:TerminateInstanceInAutoScalingGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
```

2. Then attach create a role and attached the policy with the created role.

```
aws iam attach-role-policy --policy-arn $ASG_POLICY_ARN --role-name $IAM_ROLE the policy
```

3. then download example yml from here [download the desired one](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws/examples) and edit the yml to change --nodes=1:10:k8s-worker-asg-1 with  your autoscaling group name.

For more details please check this [document](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws/README.md).